# Reset wallpaper of 2nd monitor without having connection to 2nd monitor?

Tags: mac, wallpaper

How can I reset wallpaper on the 2nd monitor without having connection to that 2nd monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset them all by deleting this file

`~/Library/Application Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db`

Alternatively, you could try opening it in something like [SQLite Free](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/sqlite-free-datum/id901631046?mt=12) - but I'm not sure what the consequences of deleting a single line from the list of wallpapers would be.